GCP Storage - Dynamically Created Folder Not Showing in Command Line Directory List
I'm running into an issue with Google Cloud Storage (GCS) where folders that are created dynamically aren't appearing when I list the directory contents from the command line.
Issue:
A folder is successfully created in GCS programmatically, but when I run gsutil ls gs://my-bucket-name/, the new folder doesn’t show up in the directory list.
However, I can confirm that the folder exists because I can see it in the GCP Console.
Troubleshooting Steps Taken:
Verified that the folder creation is successful.
Confirmed correct permissions for the bucket and folder.
Ensured I am using the correct bucket name in the gsutil command.
Questions:
Is there a known delay in how quickly dynamically created folders appear in command line listings?
Could there be any caching issues or settings in GCS that might prevent immediate visibility in the command line?
Any guidance or workarounds to ensure that newly created folders show up in command line listings would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

The problem is: "the folders do not exist".
Really! I assure you! You can check this here. It's named simulated folder. It's a fake folder. The hack here is the following: a file with the name "" (empty name) with size of 0b, is created in the path /my-folder/
Like this, you can think you have a folder, you can see it in the UI. But there is a filter enforced with the CLI that filter these empty-name-0b-size file.
Try gsutil ls -l gs://.... you should see something like this
         0  2024-11-05T08:12:13Z  gs://...../fake-folder/
TOTAL: 1 objects, 0 bytes (0 B)


To confirm this, I tested this (previous) flaw in the CLI, and it does no longer occur. The CLI has been patched and you can now see your folder even if you only have an empty-name-0b-size file.
So, update your gcloud CLI to fix the issue

Another important point is the recent evolution of Cloud Storage. As you can see, you have simulated folder, but you also have HNS (hierarchical namespace) that is pretty new and better match the traditional block storage concept with tree structure, folders, ....

Finally you have the managed folder, that is not a "folder", but only a security aspect of your folder (simulated or HNS) to be able to enforce permission on it (and inherited by all the object/folders contained in the managed folder)
